# Why can't we cancel the x from both sides in the equation $x^2=x^3$?

Tags: exponentiation

It may seem at first sight that the $x$ can be cancelled from both sides. It
doesn't make any sense that the square of a number is equal to its cube (unless it's 1) as in this case. I know that the reason of this is pretty well known. Well, as it happens, my teacher is finding it a bit too difficult in making me understand this.

How can we find the value(s) of $x$ here?Are there complex theorems behind this or is it just simply the 'basics'?

Comment: $0^2=0^3=0$ $0×2=0×3$ but $3\ne2$

Comment: You can only cancel x's if you are sure $x\neq 0$.

Comment: "is it simply the 'basics'":  We have a *lot* of groundwork built up around the theory of polynomials and their roots, most useful here being the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).  By rewording your question of finding the values of $x$ such that $x^2=x^3$ into the question of finding the values of $x$ which are roots to the polynomial equation $f(x)=x^3-x^2$, we can then use all that we know about how real numbers work., i.e. that the roots of $x^3-x^2$ are the roots of $(x-0)^2(x-1)$ which are $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\;x^2=x^3 \iff x^3-x^2=0 \iff x^2(x-1)=0\,$, then either factor can be $\,0\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2=x^3$$

First consider whether $x$ can be $0$, $0^2=0^3$. Alright, so $x=0$ is a possible solution.

Next, we consider what if $x \neq 0$, now we can divide by $x^2$.

and the equation become $1=x$.

Hence, in summary, $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Cancelling means dividing here, We have to make sure we do not divide by $0$ accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-x^3=x^2(1-x)=(x)(x)(1-x)=0$$
so
$$x=0$$
$$x=0$$
$$x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Isn't $x=0$ a solution too?

Answer (score 0):

We want to find the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\colon x^2=x^3\}$. Clearly $0\in S$. Now suppose that $x\neq 0$. Then  $1/x^2$ exists and 
$$
x^2=x^3\iff\frac{1}{x^2}x^2=\frac{1}{x^2}x^3\iff x=1.
$$
Thus $S=\{0,1\}$.